# different value from Matlab function NTSC2RGB when multiplying with the given yiq to rgb conversion matrix?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am using matlab function ntsc2rgb but its output differs from the actual multiplication of the matrix function given on the matlab webpage.

![YIQ to RGB conversion matrix]http://www.mathworks.in/help/releases/R2013b/images/ref/eqn1248880083.png

http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/ntsc2rgb.html
nI is a 3 dimensional ntsc value matrix.

```
   disp(nI([1:1],[1:1],[1:3])));
   fprintf('after\n');
   nI=ntsc2rgb(nI);
   disp(nI([1:1],[1:1],[1:3])));

Matlab shows this output 
before
1   1   1   0.956863
1   1   2   -0.165627
1   1   3   -0.0367254
after
1   1   1   0.719921
1   1   2   0.9519
1   1   3   1

But actual value should be 
value of   1   1   1   0.776073
value of   1   1   2   1.025472
value of   1   1   3   1.077615
```

Before value are coming from some above code, After value are coming after using the matlab ntsc2rgb function.

And actual value are calculated by using the YIQ to RGB matrix shown in the picture above.

Comment: The link you posted says that *"Both rgbmap and yiqmap contain intensities in the range 0 to 1.0"*, which may be relevant.

Comment: @RogerRowland As shown in the input above all the intensities value are in the range 0-1. If I missed something, please elaborate.

Comment: Did I misunderstand those negative values? And did I misunderstand the "actual value"'s > 1?

Comment: @RogerRowland I have edited the question. Please look at edited version and if we not consider those negative values, then also 'after value' will not match with the value of 'actual value'. My doubt is matlab uses the above matrix attached in picture or not for ntsc2rgb.

Comment: Please reduce your example to the relevant size. Your code to print the data is irrelevant, disp would reduce the code to three lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color matlab outputs is absolutely correct. The correct steps are:

1. Normalize your invalid input to the 0..1 range
2. Apply the transformation matrix
3. Some points might be outside the RGB color space, map to the closest point within the RGB space.

Comment: What I did to this problem is find the RGB without changing any YIQ value then if there is any value which is greater than 1(say max). Divide all the RGB value with this max value.